# Would QGIS 2.8 print composer_templates work in QGIS 2.14?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, print-templates

I have created some maps using print composer of Qgis version LTR 2.8.9. and saved them as templates.

I am planning to upgrade to 2.14.1 LTR version and I will completely uninstall Qgis in order to have a proper clean install of the new version. I will backup the folder composer_templates from `c:\users\user\.qgis folder`. Will the templates be ok with the new version? Has any one tried the same even with other versions?

Comment: Why uninstall? You can run both at the same time.

Comment: Well I have a project in which I add information from time to time and update a cloud map. If i open the project with a newer version then is useless in the old ver. I would prefer not to have two projects... for each version!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, newer versions of QGIS maintain compatibility with older version's projects, templates, styles, etc.

There is very very rare exceptions to this. Eg QGIS 3.x has dropped compatibility with some styling options from QGIS 1.x version projects. You'd need to open and resave these projects in a 2.x version to upgrade them before opening in 3.x.